# Facebook app request issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a Facebook application where the user can invite their friends and gain points once their request gets accepted. I have used the latest request dialog to cater to my needs, but I have run into a problem.

The scenario is that suppose there are four users **A, B, C and D**.

**A, B, C** send the application invitation request to **D**. But, when **D** receives the request, he receives all of the request_ids in the query string (that is, by **A, B and C**).

The other problem is that the request notification is merged, that is, I get the notification like "**A, B and C** have sent you the request to join the application". How do I make the request to be separate for each user, so I can track whose request got accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do anything with this behavior of Requests, all requests to the same users will be grouped and separation of requests isn't something Facebook provide...

> If a user clicks 'Accept' on a Request, they will be sent to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. This URL will contain an additional GET parameter `request_ids`, which is a comma delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon

**Update:**
You may consider separation of requests within your application.
In new flow requests not deleted automatically and you need to remove 'em, so it should be pretty easy to display those requests in your application allowing user to trigger some action  and only then remove that request. There is no problem to check if user have pending requests via Graph API.

You should be aware of fact that once user clicked request notification on Facebook, notification will disappear and number of requests will only be visible in application "bookmark".

Comment: But, thats the real issue. I believe this used to happen but has been changed with the latest API.

Comment: You are correct, this was changed 1 Jan 2012 (see [Improvements to Requests 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/) blog post for more info).

Comment: I don't understand why your workflow would need to change though, you'll still get all 3 requests in this scenario and mark all three as accepted

Comment: @user1178401, I've updated my answer with some info which may interest you. But I think there is no reason to complicate flow that works in a manner users know it. Remember, surprising user isn't always good thing...

Comment: @juicy Scripter . They want me to prepare a separate request for each invitation and upon acceptance identify whose request got accepted. Thats a business decision